# Selecting only some columns from a table

Tags: mysql, select, concat

I have a MySQL table that consists of around 200 columns.

The name of each column is `col_i` (i=1 ,2,..200).

Suppose I have to select only first 50 columns, how should I proceed?

I found about the `concat()` function, but I am unable to use it.

I know this can be done manually, for example by writing:

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, ..., col_50 FROM table_1 ;
```

...but writing each column name is pretty tiring. I am looking for a loop approach if it is possible.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a job for Dynamic SQL against the information_schema

Suppose the table you are doing the `SELECT` against is `mydb.mytable` and the query looks like this:

```
SELECT col_1,col_2,...,col_n FROM mydb.mytable WHERE id = 27;
```

You want the first 50 columns in the `SELECT` list ? Here it is:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1048576;
SET @first_column = 1;
SET @final_column = 50;
SET @db = 'mydb';
SET @tb = 'mytable';
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name ORDER BY ordinal_position)
INTO @select_column_list
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema=@db
AND table_name=@tb
AND ordinal_position >= @first_column
AND ordinal_position <= @final_column;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ',@select_column_list,' FROM ',@db,'.',@tb,' WHERE id = 27');
PREPARE s FROM @sql;
EXECUTE s;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

Want columns 10 - 18 in the `SELECT` list ? Do this:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1048576;
SET @first_column = 10;
SET @final_column = 18;
SET @db = 'mydb';
SET @tb = 'mytable';
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name ORDER BY ordinal_position)
INTO @select_column_list
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema=@db
AND table_name=@tb
AND ordinal_position >= @first_column
AND ordinal_position <= @final_column;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ',@select_column_list,' FROM ',@db,'.',@tb,' WHERE id = 27');
PREPARE s FROM @sql;
EXECUTE s;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

and so forth.

If you want to see the crafted SQL, do this before running the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT @sql\G
PREPARE s FROM @sql;
EXECUTE s;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!